# Create Automated Horizontal Scrolling Tiles with different scrolling with pure CSS

Tags: css, slider, flexbox, metro-ui-css

I want to create news horizontal scrolling tiles slider with pure css without JS 
[image: Horizontal scrolling tiles slider]

I tried using FlexBox,

```css
.spotlight-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.spotlight-wrapper .spotlight {
  list-style: none;
  height: 230px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: bottom;
  padding: 0;
}
.spotlight-wrapper .spotlight li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
.spotlight-wrapper .spotlight li.small {
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
}
.spotlight-wrapper .spotlight li.medium {
  width: 220px;
  height: 105px;
  /*
     * Idea to fix it, but will cause
     * issue if the medium tile in the
     * bottom level, and there are 2 small
     * tiles next to it in the top level
    */
  /* & + .small + .small{
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     justify-content: bottom;
     margin-top: 120px;
     margin-left: -110px;
    } */
}
.spotlight-wrapper .spotlight li.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight-wrapper">
 <ul class="spotlight">
  <li>Tile #1</li>
  <li class="small">Tile #2</li>
  <li class="small">Tile #3</li>
  <li class="medium">Tile #9</li>
  <li class="medium">Tile #10</li>
  <li>Tile #2</li>
  <li class="medium red">Tile #1</li>
  <li class="small red">Tile #2</li>
  <li class="small red">Tile #3</li>
  <li>Tile #5</li>
  <li>Tile #7</li>
  <li>Tile #8</li>
  <li class="medium">Tile #9</li>
  <li class="medium">Tile #10</li>
  <li>Tile #11</li>
  <li>Tile #12</li>
  <li class="small">Tile #13</li>
  <li>Tile #14</li>
  <li>Tile #15</li>
  <li>Tile #16</li>
  <li>Tile #17</li>
  <li>Tile #18</li>
  <li>Tile #19</li>
  <li>Tile #20</li>
 </ul>
```

But if you check the red tiles, its not aligned the correct way,
i can fix it using margins (check the commented block) but will cause other issue if the wide tile is in the bottom row, and there are 2 small tiles in the next block,

Also if there are only one small tile, empty space will be created.

Comment: You may want to start your troubleshooting here: **`justify-content: bottom`** (there is no such value). For valid values and other alignment options that may help you see here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Very nice one, thanks for sharing, hope the answer light up there

Comment: maybe column CSS is more accurate ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgEGvG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I work a lot with flexbox and I very much like what you are trying to achieve and will modify a few things of my own to work like that.

Secondly, you have failed to tell flexbox how to flex the `li` elements. Defining only `width` and `height` on flexed elements forces flexbox to use only those values and is not flexible at all.

**UPDATE**

A flexbox row cannot put different sized boxes on top of each other on the **same** row (the same is true for flexbox columns with rows). This actually means that if you want your solution you will need a main column with 2 rows (`ul`) each `height: 105px` and put `li` in either row where appropriate.

Another option would be a single flexbox row (`ul`) with child `li`'s that are wrapping flexbox rows, actually nesting `small` and `medium` classes.

I think I would opt for the second solution.

As you can see from the code, your main 'lightstrip' has become a row of boxes with each box containing 3 elements: 2 `spot`'s and a 'strip'.

I removed the reference to `ul` and `li` elements, making it more flexible. This way you can use any kind of container as a lightbox.

```css
ul,ol,li { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 }

.armature {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.lightstrip {
  height: 210px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  width:  210px;
  height: 210px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.spot {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.3);
}
.strip {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="armature">
    <div class="lightstrip">
        <div class="lightbox"><div class="spot" ></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="strip"></div></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><div class="spot" ></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="strip"></div></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><div class="strip"></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="spot" ></div></div>

        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="spot" ></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="strip"></li></ul>
        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="strip"></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="spot" ></li></ul>
        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="spot" ></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="strip"></li></ul>

        <div class="lightbox"><div class="spot" ></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="strip"></div></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><div class="spot" ></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="strip"></div></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><div class="strip"></div><div class="spot"></div><div class="spot" ></div></div>

        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="spot" ></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="strip"></li></ul>
        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="strip"></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="spot" ></li></ul>
        <ul class="lightbox"><li class="spot" ></li><li class="spot"></li><li class="strip"></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, still gonna need to update it a little so it's working with loop rendering (i'm going to use with O365's SharePoint display template)

Comment: No mention! Obviously, this approach can be implemented in various ways. But, while you're at it, make **lightbox, spot** and **strip** `position: relative` and their **:before** and **:after** `position: absolute` and you can easily overlay text or badges (needs a bit of `z-index: ...` tinkering).

Comment: Here's a pen of mine on Codepen [Responsive filmstrip and thumblist](http://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/ZbrpQO) which might give you further ideas on overlaying text and showing content in your strip.